# how to calculate Sin(X) with array

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x,sum;
    double[] series = new double[30];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a num: ");
    x = input.nextInt();
    sum = x;
    for (int i = 3; i <= 27 ; i+=2){
        int a = 0;
        a++;
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++ ){
            series[a] =  x/j;
            System.out.println(series[a] );
        }
    }
    //if (i == 27){
        boolean add = true; 
        for (int b = 1; b <= 27 ; b++ ){
            if (add == true){
                sum -= series[b];
                }
            else {
                sum += series[b];
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

so what I am trying to do is store the result of (x/j) in my 'series' array...? that's mean the x^(i)/i! thing....did I misunderstand the way of how to calculate Sin(X)?

Comment: What makes you think there's anything wrong?  That is, what is the actual problem you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Sin(X) is the sum of x to the power of n, divided by n, alternating between negative and positive on each iteration. Note that n increases by 2 on each iteration.

[image]

[Read This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

Comment: Where does it stop? Do you just have to run it forever to make it completely accurate?